# How to get the value of a button inside click eventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to show the value of a button when that button is clicked. If I write the code for this inside the eventListener the alert pops up but there is no text showing.

I have tried moving the alert above the eventListener and inside the for loop and this shows the correct values when the page loads.

HTML for buttons:

```
<button class="buttonA" value="A">A</button>
<button class="buttonB" value="B">B</button>
<button class="buttonC" value="C">C</button>
<button class="buttonD" value="D">D</button>
<button class="buttonE" value="E">E</button>
<button class="buttonF" value="F">F</button>
<button class="buttonG" value="G">G</button>
<button class="buttonH" value="H">H</button>
<button class="buttonI" value="I">I</button>
<button class="buttonJ" value="J">J</button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>

var allButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button[class^=button]');

for (var i = 0; i < allButtons.length; i++) {
    var value = allButtons[i].value;
    alert(value);  //this works and shows all values on page load
    allButtons[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        try {
            alert(value); //this shows a blank pop-up when a button is clicked
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to to add a parameter argument e.g. `e` to the event listener or use `arguments[0]`.

Then you can use `e.target.value` to get the value of the button.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button[class^=button]').forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', onClickEvent);
});

function onClickEvent(e) {
  try {
    alert(e.target.value); // or `arguments[0].target.value`
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="buttonA" value="A">A</button>
<button class="buttonB" value="B">B</button>
<button class="buttonC" value="C">C</button>
<button class="buttonD" value="D">D</button>
<button class="buttonE" value="E">E</button>
<button class="buttonF" value="F">F</button>
<button class="buttonG" value="G">G</button>
<button class="buttonH" value="H">H</button>
<button class="buttonI" value="I">I</button>
<button class="buttonJ" value="J">J</button>
```

### Update

Here is a more elegant modern way that uses object destructuring and a shared class.

```js
const onClickEvent = ({ target: { value } }) => {
  try {
    alert(value);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

document.querySelectorAll('.alert-button').forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', onClickEvent);
});
```

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center; /* horizontal alignment */
  align-items: center;     /* vertical alignment   */
}

.alert-button {
  margin: 0.25em;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<button class="alert-button" value="A">A</button>
<button class="alert-button" value="B">B</button>
<button class="alert-button" value="C">C</button>
<button class="alert-button" value="D">D</button>
<button class="alert-button" value="E">E</button>
<button class="alert-button" value="F">F</button>
<button class="alert-button" value="G">G</button>
<button class="alert-button" value="H">H</button>
<button class="alert-button" value="I">I</button>
<button class="alert-button" value="J">J</button>
```