# javascript - get clicked button value when all buttons are named the same

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where I have lots of buttons in a table on my web page.

Each button has the same name, but a different value set.

When I want to extract the button value, wouldn't using the below mean I am not getting the unique button value - the one that was actually clicked?

How can I get around that?

Thanks!!

```
document.getElementById("myBtn").value;
```

Comment: Ids should not be duplicated in HTML. use different ids, or instead use class name or tags

Comment: What does the code look like where you're invoking the functionality when any of the buttons is clicked? Can you add that here? If you're properly using `element.addEventListener()`, you can extract the calling button from the `event` callback parameter.

Comment: Why not get the clicked button value from the click event it self?

Comment: Please research your inquiry before posting - duplicate questions are not permitted here in the interest of content quality. This is  a duplicate of [How to get the value of a button inside click eventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57906053/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-button-inside-click-eventlistener)

Comment: I have been researching myself but of the millions of stackoverflow links, it can be hard to find the answer.

Comment: OP mentions `name` not `id`. Multiple buttons can have `name` attributes with same values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think some of the comments / answers may be a little confusing. It might help to bind the same handler to each button and have it handle accordingly.

As @chr stated, try using something which will allow you to query all the buttons you want to attach the same click event to.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".myBtn");
```

Is one approach, however I suggest looking at how you can play with that query selector if you want to be a little more generic and get all buttons within your table.

Next, I suggest using a common click handler for each. In a javascript event, you are passed an event object as a parameter which will allow you to get information on the DOM element which initiated the event.

```
function myClickHandler(event) {
   var value = event.target.value;
   // Do stuff
}    

document.querySelectorAll(".myBtn").forEach(btn => {
    btn.addEventListener("click", myClickHandler);
});
```

Comment: thanks you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

First of all an `id` should be a unique identifier on the document.

If it is not unique you should use a class like:
`document.querySelectorAll(".myBtn");`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it might not be practical to `id` each button in a table. Lets imagine you have a buttons table like

```js
function getButton(el){
  console.log(el.target.value);
}
```

```html
<table onclick="getButton(event)">
  <tr>
    <td><button name="button" value="1-1">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="1-2">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="1-3">Click</button></td>
  </tr >
  <tr>
    <td><button name="button" value="2-1">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="2-2">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="2-3">Click</button></td>
  </tr >
  <tr>
    <td><button name="button" value="3-1">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="3-2">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="3-3">Click</button></td>
  </tr >
</table>
```

So when you click the button, you get the value. However this might not be what you are asking. If you would like to select a particular button in the table by JS dynamically, then you may easily do so by indexing the buttons through CSS selector logic as follows;

```js
function getButtonValue(r,c){
  var el = document.querySelector(`table tr:nth-child(${r}) td:nth-child(${c}) button`);
  console.log(el.value);
}

getButtonValue(2,3);
```

```css
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(3) button { border       : 1px solid red;
                                               border-radius: 3px
                                             }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><button name="button" value="1-1">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="1-2">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="1-3">Click</button></td>
  </tr >
  <tr>
    <td><button name="button" value="2-1">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="2-2">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="2-3">Click</button></td>
  </tr >
  <tr>
    <td><button name="button" value="3-1">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="3-2">Click</button></td>
    <td><button name="button" value="3-3">Click</button></td>
  </tr >
</table>
```